# No mouse cursor in Icewind Dale

Tags: icewind-dale

I'm playing Icewind Dale - Enhanced version. Problem is that the mouse pointer will not appear on screen. Drivers have been updated with no result.

What can I do?

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: Did you try to change the 'hardware cursor' setting from options?